# C# Create getter delegate for specific item in ICollection or IEnumerable

Tags: c#, delegates, simulation, ienumerable

I am trying to create a dynamic `Environment` class that hosts a simulation's real-time data. I want to be able to register specific "environment variables" such as collections, fields, and so on. Using this, consuming classes would be able to see what variables are available and request them individually.

I would like to make this reflection-based so that any future developer can take an existing class and incorporate it into the `Environment` without having to implement additional features. If possible, I would like to add support for the `ICollection` and/or `IEnumerable` interfaces, so existing classes that implement these can be used. For example, being able to register a `Dictionary` would mean that the environment would list all key-value pairs as environment variables, where the key is turned into a unique string and the value is what would be provided if requested.

An example of what how it might be implemented:

```
public class Environment
{
  private delegate object GetterDelegate();

  private Dictionary<string, GetterDelegate> environmentVariables_;

  public IEnumerable<string> EnvironmentVariables
  {
    get => environmentVariables_.Keys;
  }

  public object this[string name]
  {
    get => environmentVariables_[name]();
  }

  public Environment()
  {
    environmentVariables_ = new Dictionary<string, GetterDelegate>();
  } 

  public void Register( string name, ICollection collection )
  {
    int i = 0;
    foreach( var element in collection )
      environmentVariables_.Add( $"name_{i++}", GetterDelegate );
  }

  public void Register( string name, IEnumerable enumerable )
  {
    int i = 0;
    foreach( var element in enumerable )
      environmentVariables_.Add( $"name_{i++}", GetterDelegate );
  }

  public void Register<T,V>( string name, Dictionary<T,V> dictionary )
  {
    // TODO: Custom logic instead of Key.ToString()
    foreach( var pair in dictionary )
      environmentVariables_.Add( $"name_{pair.Key.ToString()}", GetterDelegate );
  }

  public void Register( string name, FieldInfo field )
  {
    environmentVariables_.Add( name, GetterDelegate );
  }

}
```

To accomplish this, I would like to be able to dynamically compile getter methods that can directly access the specific element instead of having to call `IEnumerable.ElementAt()` every time, since that can be incredibly slow depending on the class's implementation. And since `ICollection` implements `IEnumerable`, it could likely be handled in the same manner in most cases.

**Is it possible to compile a DynamicMethod that can directly obtain a specific IEnumerable element without having to call ElementAt(), which would likely enumerate over the entire collection until the proper element is found?** I would welcome a better way to go about solving this problem as well if this is too roundabout.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `IEnumerable` or `ICollection` if you need to be able to access items by index.  Neither of those interfaces support that.

`IList` is the interface that represents data that can be accessed by index.

Comment: That is absolutely the case, but I am trying to support data structures that do not implement `IList` without having to modify them or write adapters for them. Thus I would much prefer to use a getter delegate if possible.

Comment: @Haus If you want to support data structures that don't provide the operation you need, you either need to modify them, not use them, or write an adapter that adds the needed behavior to them.  There's no option to just have the behavior you want when the object doesn't provide it, and you don't add it yourself.